# Strange lighting anomaly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was on my adventure maps build server and was flying about with my elytra and noticed four bright patches of light on the ground. I swooped down to break what I thought was a torch causing it, but there was nothing there. Just light sitting out in the middle of the night.

[image: Anomaly?]

I'm not sure if "anomaly" is the correct word for this, but I have never seen anything like this before. I've checked the world and there is no lighting, even way above the strange patches of light. I uploaded this world to my server.pro server without anything bad happening, and this is not anything of major concern to me, but I would like to know what cause's this and how to stop it. Research only comes up with people wanting to manipulate something like this ([beep beep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212650/minecraft-creating-light-without-a-source-block)) without even knowing that it's possible.

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using?

Comment: Its in 1.10.2 . Probably should have added that to the question.

Comment: Does it appear even the night after or it disappears?

Comment: If just stays there. The light level at the centre stays the same during daytime to (F3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problems like this before.  If there were blocks that produced light, like a torch, and it was removed with an external program, in my case Mcedit, the light is never removed.  This is because minecraft bakes light levels into a chunk, and when a chunk is edited, the lighting is rebaked.  Now, some 3rd party programs or even plugins, if not adequately programmed, may skip the call the rebaking the lightmap, resulting in incorrect lighting.  Placing light emiting blocks may fix it, if not delete the chunk via Mcedit and let minecraft regenerate it.  If that's not an option, an nbt editor can be used to painstakingly fix it.

Comment: Makes sense. I uploaded the map to server.pro, it may have done what you say.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably a glitch, place blocks in the center of the light and it would should away

Comment: I have tried this. I kind of experienced something similair now that you remind me, when I was playing cosmicpvp and my spawners weren't working, because there was little patch's of light sources in corners etc. But this is different nothing makes it gone.